# Edge drop-down issue with jquery

Tags: jquery, microsoft-edge

I have a dropdown, seen [here](https://www.drury.edu/evening-and-online/majors-minors-even). On any browser, other than Edge, it is performing perfectly. If you click the first drop-down either one or more dropdowns will display, based on your selection. On Edge, however, the dropdown is only working about every other time. Other times the first one is shown but no additional ones will display upon click. I believe it's an issue with my jquery not being fully supported. Any suggestions for what I can try?

Comment: Right click and inspect your code. Use your developer tools. Open Console and refresh page. Now try to simulate your error. If you get a red error with some code or error message, please post it.

Comment: @McKenzie, I try to check your site in MS Edge and find that drop downs are working fine without any issue. I had tested it many times but it did not failed single time. Here is my testing result. https://gifyu.com/image/TG8X There are some JQuery related errors in console which you can try to correct it but it is possible that it can be related with other code. You can again try to make a test on your side and if issue persist than try to post a sample code of your drop downs. We will try to make a test with it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, I am still experiencing the issue. Sometimes it will work on page load and then other times when I leave the page to go to another and then back to the dropdown tool page, it will stop working suddenly. I will comment a code sample below.

Answer (score 0):

You have about 18 error messages in your code. They might be the issue.

Open your developer tools when you are on that page. Refresh the page and click console tab. You will see all your errors. On the left is a description and on the right is the file and the line number.

[image]